# Get child from node and pass into attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

sorry for this rivial question but at the moment i can not figure it out.

I have an node in there are childs, i want these child and "print" these directly in an attribute. Please take a look at the code:

```
<fo:declarations>
                <xsl:for-each select="//lb">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./dv-group/dv/download">

<xsl:value-of select="." />
<pdf:embedded-file filename="<xsl:value-of select="." />" src="url(test:///C:/Users/muster/Desktop/template_test/data/Mappe1.xlsx)"/>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:declarations>
```

I have try it with a variable but that doesn't work too.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is called an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates): in attribute values on a literal result element (and in certain attributes of some `xsl:` instructions too) you can enclose XPath expressions in braces and they will be evaluated and their result substituted in the output:

```
<pdf:embedded-file filename="{.}" src="url(test:///C:/Users/muster/Desktop/template_test/data/Mappe1.xlsx)"/>
```

If you want a literal brace character in an attribute that is interpreted as an AVT you must double it.